# HSQLDB - Can't update identity column

Tags: hsqldb, rdbms

I have a column like this:

```
MYID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

I know that when doing an `INSERT` it's possible to override the generated value.
However once the row has been created I can't find a way to use an `UPDATE` to change the value.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GENERATED ALWAYS` means what is says. You cannot override the values. If you want the system to simply ignore the values you provide, you can use `OVERRIDING USER VALUES` in the INSERT statement. Otherwise you cannot supply values for the GENERATED column. Values for columns defined as `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` can be overridden by the user.